# Unable to identify element with content-desc attribute from UI Automator Viewer, tried so many possibilities

Tags: appium

I am having hard time locating the button with content-desc as "Sign Out"
I have tried below codes none of them seems to work :frowning:

1.driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(“new UiSelector().text(“Sign Out”)”).click();
2.driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(“UiSelector().description(“Sign Out”)”).click();
3.driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(“text(“Sign Out”)”).click();
4.driver.findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator(“content-desc(“Sign Out”)”);
5. driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@content-desc=‘Sign Out’]").click();
6.driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@content-desc,‘Sign’]").click();

This is a Hybrid mobile app

[UI Automateviewer image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKJwd.png)

Comment: Following up on this. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on exact java piece, but following python code works well -
driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().descriptionContains("Text")')

Comment: This is now deprecated: driver.find_element(by=ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, value='new UiSelector().description("Text")')